# errors in flutter SDK

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-studio, dart

When I press on any methods or properties I can not see any info and shows for me like xml file and all the words in the page (null)
so anyone has the resolve for that and thanks

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Install the Flutter plugin for IntelliJ/Android Studio?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Run following command in your **Terminal** window and see detail error and configure your Flutter SDK

flutter doctor

Comment: all arguments are correct

Comment: make sure your **Flutter SDK** path are set to right location.